# Jquery Ui drag and drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I am dragging my elements from left nav to a droppable area using jquery UI,what should i do if i have to remove dragged elements from droppable area? The simple functionality that I am expecting is that when it is dragged out of the container it should be deleted. It should not snap back to the container. here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".txtI").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});

$("#phone").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        ui.draggable.clone().removeClass("txtI").addClass("txt2").appendTo(this);
    }
}).sortable({
    items: "div",
    sort: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: you mean you drop them outside of dropable ?

Comment: yes right, when i drag them again out of dropable area and drop somewhere else, its like this I have some UI controls which i want to add to the main container using drag and drop, at some point when user wants to delete the UI controls he has added, he just have to drag them out of container.

Comment: you need to make everything else droppable too, but if dropable is your current area you do your stuff else remove element :P

Comment: @JayKay In right side container are you appending the original element or clone element from left side?

Comment: @karthik, I am appending clone element from the left side.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your inputs. This is achieved by a simple line:

ui.draggable.remove();